# Line Renderer's line is being keep connected at (0, 0, 0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I wanted to connect a line with those two game objects. However as you can see at a picture, the line is kept connecting with 0, 0, 0 positions.

[image]

Line Renderer's Index1 value is getting position value very normally.

I have no idea what is the problem with this.

here is the code that I used.

```
public LineRenderer line;
public GameObject target;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "SHIP")
    {
        target = collision.gameObject;

        kinetic_attaek_effect.SetPosition(0, Transform.position);

        kinetic_attaek_effect.SetPosition(1, target.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position);
    }       
}
```

Comment: put a `Debug.Log(transform.position);` above this and tells us the value: `kinetic_attaek_effect.SetPosition(0, Transform.position);` also i guess you are using transform.position with a small t and not with a capital one

Comment: out of interest where is the code showing the line renders..

Comment: Btw: Please shrink this `target.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position` to simply using `target.transform.position`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure useWorldSpace is disabled

```
lineRenderer.useWorldSpace = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
kinetic_attaek_effect.SetPosition(0, transform.position);

kinetic_attaek_effect.SetPosition(1, target.gameObject.transform.position);
```

`transform` is the property of `gameObject` that has type `Transform`.

More [info](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.html).